navbar links does not work, won't scroll through page
I am new hier and I've been working on my portfolio page https://martina.codefactory.live/ , but unfortunately, the links in the navbar aren't functioning properly, when I click on them they want scroll through page. For each section, I've assigned an ID and used the corresponding ID as the href for the links in the navbar, which should typically work. Strangely, though, everything seems to function correctly when I open the developer tools or when I open my site on mobile device.
Oddly, the links in the footer work perfectly fine, so it seems to be specific to the navbar.
Here's a snippet of the code:
<nav>
      <a href="/"><img src="images/Screenshot 2024-02-29 085548.png" alt="" class="logo" /></a>
      <ul id="sidemenu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" >About</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <i class="fas fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="closemenu()"></i></ul>
      <i class="fas fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="openmenu()"></i>
    </nav>

    <!-- hero section  -->
    <div class="hero" id="home">
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>
          Hello, I am <br /><span>Martina</span>
          Brkanić
        </h1>
        <p>Frontend Developer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- about section  -->
    <div class="about" id="about">
...

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have an idea how to solve it?

Ensured that each section has a unique ID (#home, #about, #portfolio, #contact) and that the href attributes in the navbar links match these IDs.
Verified that there are no JavaScript errors in the console.
Checked the CSS styling for any potential conflicts or overlaps.
Tested on different browsers and devices- on my mobile device links works fine.
I found hier that I should try overflow: visible !importatn - still not working


Your problem is not with the anchors themselves - going to https://martina.codefactory.live#about in my browser, jumps to the relevant section immediately. The problem is, that clicking your navigation items doesn't actually do anything - the URL doesn't change to include the fragment at the end, and therefor no jump happens either. And that is because the pseudo elements on the li, that you used for the hover effect, are on top of the links, so you can't actually click the links any more. [...]

[...] Either move the pseudo elements from the li to the links themselves; or applypointer-events: none to the pseudo elements, so that the click can "pass through" them.

"Thanks! Applying pointer-events: none has solved my problem!"
